# How to inherit from a css file in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I believe this is very simple but I cannot find a solution to it. I am unable to inherit my css classes in my js file.

This is my render function from the js file:

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <div className='smallSectionWrapper'>
                <div className='oneItem'>
                    <h3>Name</h3>
                    <p>John</p>
                </div>
                <div className='oneItem'>
                    <h3>Middle Name</h3>
                    <p>Johny</p>
                </div>
                <div className='oneItem'>
                    <h3>Surname</h3>
                    <p>Johnson</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my scss file:

```
.oneItem {
  width: 300px;
}
.smallSectionWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

What I expect to render:

[image]

What I actually render:

[image]

After inspecting this it appears that the classes are inherited but without the properties mentioned in the class. I'm fairly new to React so is it possible that I am missing a step?

Comment: I don't see any problem, to be honest! https://jsfiddle.net/qejx9rwv/

Comment: How did you import the scss file and where?

Comment: I think you're missing the import css in your js file. 
import "./style.css";

Comment: You should import the SCSS file on top of the javascript file. `import './styles.scss'`

Comment: Yup that was the case, altho I don't see the other js files on this project importing a css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing import in .js file:

```
import '<<your scss path>>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The files / code you provided appear to work for me. Perhaps double check that you aren't using a different responsive layout inside of your console view

**regarding styling:**
Make sure that if you are using SCSS inside your react App that you:

- install node-sass (npm i/yarn add node-sass)
- import the scss file into the correct file OR one that the component will be rendered as a child to.

  i.e.

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.scss';

const Tester = () => {
    return (
        <div className='smallSectionWrapper'>
            <div className='oneItem'>
                <h3>Name</h3>
                <p>Carl</p>
            </div>
            <div className='oneItem'>
                <h3>Middle Name</h3>
                <p>Johny</p>
            </div>
            <div className='oneItem'>
                <h3>Surname</h3>
                <p>Johnson</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tester
```

Also consider using nested SCSS for specificity

```
.smallSectionWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  .oneItem {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

You may wish to look into [styled components](https://styled-components.com/) as these will allow you to write your styling directly in the component *which can be easier to extract the component for re-use in the future*.